# SSD suddenly failed

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance, ssd

I've been gaming last night and noticed that the whole system lags for 10 seconds each 10 minutes or so (completely frozen) and goes back to normal.

Today when I started it up, it said "windows couldn't start correctly" and opened up system repair which took forever so I just canceled it after an hour.

I booted from a backup HDD and the SSD volume looks like it's corrupted, couldn't open it (says: E:/ is not accessible)

This happened to me once before, the exact scenario, and i had to format the SSD and re-install  Windows. since then the SSD's speed never hit 500mb (only 100mb).

What could be the issue?

The specs are:

```
Sabertooth x58
12GB DDR3 RAM
i7 960 @ 3.2Ghz (Overclocked to 3.6ghz)
[SSD] Corsair Performance 3 128GB
```

Comment: What's your power supply like?

Comment: 1000 Watt Corsair Power Supply

Comment: SSD disks are well known to have a limited lifespan (based on number of operations).  How long have you owned this particular disk?